# Tutorial for Laravel 4 - Authentication

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, cartalyst-sentry

I looked around and found some tutorials about `Laravel 4` *authentication* using `Sentry` or `Confide` and `Entrust`. Which are good but a little vague for me, I am `Laravel` beginner and this is my first framework.

Does anyone know of any tutorial or suggestions implementing user authentication with user roles.

Here is what I am trying to make. 
- Its an internal website for work. Where writers can sign in and submit articles.
- Admins Can go over those articles.
- These articles are not public so no one can view them.
- Writers cannot see each others articles, but admins have access to everything.

I am just looking for tutorial that goes over user roles and how to implement them.

#### Edit

*This is what I ended up doing.*

After Installing Sentry in the way specified by [@Antonio Carlos Ribeiro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1959747/antonio-carlos-ribeiro).

I had *Users*,*Groups* and few other tables (I just had to use user and groups).

Here is my seeder that I initially used for creating users and groups. It can be made more efficient, but for anyone who wants to just get started this would work.

```
class SentrySeeder extends Seeder {

public function run()
{
    DB::table('users')->delete();
    DB::table('groups')->delete();
    DB::table('users_groups')->delete();

    Sentry::getUserProvider()->create(array(
        'email'       => 'admin@admin.com',
        'password'    => "admin",
        'first_name'  => 'John',
        'last_name'   => 'McClane',
        'activated'   => 1,
    ));

    Sentry::getUserProvider()->create(array(
        'email'       => 'user@user.com',
        'password'    => "user",
        'first_name'  => 'Saad',
        'last_name'   => 'Kabir',
        'activated'   => 1,
    ));

    Sentry::getUserProvider()->create(array(
        'email'       => 'jack@user.com',
        'password'    => "user",
        'first_name'  => 'Jack',
        'last_name'   => 'Doe',
        'activated'   => 1,
    ));

    Sentry::getUserProvider()->create(array(
        'email'       => 'jon@user.com',
        'password'    => "user",
        'first_name'  => 'Jon',
        'last_name'   => 'Doe',
        'activated'   => 1,
    ));

    Sentry::getGroupProvider()->create(array(
        'name'        => 'Admin',
        'permissions' => array('admin' => 1),
    ));

    Sentry::getGroupProvider()->create(array(
        'name'        => 'Writer',
        'permissions' => array('writer' => 1),
    ));



    // Assign user permissions
    $adminUser  = Sentry::getUserProvider()->findByLogin('admin@admin.com');
    $adminGroup = Sentry::getGroupProvider()->findByName('Admin');
    $adminUser->addGroup($adminGroup);


    $userUser  = Sentry::getUserProvider()->findByLogin('user@user.com');
    $userGroup = Sentry::getGroupProvider()->findByName('Writer');
    $userUser->addGroup($userGroup);

    $userUser  = Sentry::getUserProvider()->findByLogin('jack@user.com');
    $userGroup = Sentry::getGroupProvider()->findByName('Writer');
    $userUser->addGroup($userGroup);

    $userUser  = Sentry::getUserProvider()->findByLogin('jon@user.com');
    $userGroup = Sentry::getGroupProvider()->findByName('Writer');
    $userUser->addGroup($userGroup);
}
```

}

After adding the initial users I was using a form to add new users, So in my controller I had something like this. Again this is just for learning/testing the framework, original implementation is very different. But for testing purposes this should work.

Assuming you have a form that submits to a controller@function, you can have something like this,

```
$user = Sentry::getUserProvider()->create(array(
            'email'       => Input::get('email'),
            'password'    => Input::get('password'),
            'first_name'  => Input::get('first_name'),
            'last_name'   => Input::get('last_name'),
            'activated'   => 1,
        ));

        $writerGroup = Sentry::getGroupProvider()->findByName('writer');

        $user->addGroup($writerGroup);
```

Rest you can find in Sentry documentation:
[Sentry Docs](http://docs.cartalyst.com/sentry-2/installation/laravel-4)

Feel free to edit this question to make it more informative or add new examples.

Comment: Shopping-list questions ("Please do my research for me and post a list of links") are not appropriate here. There's a [meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/158809/172661) here that explains why that is the case. Google and Bing both specialize in searching for things and returning links to the results. Voting to close as not constructive. Good luck.

Comment: I have already done the research and that is why I mentioned Confide and Entrust. I have a working laravel blog installed using them. I was just asking if someone knows of anything else that might be closer to what I need. If you dont have anything constructive to add, why bother.

Comment: You should read the [faq] and [about] pages here regarding conduct toward others, and how the site works in general. There are guidelines here for a reason, and users do most of the moderation here. I was being polite by explaining my vote to close (and polite enough not to downvote). I'd appreciate you being polite as well. If the guidelines here are not to your liking, please feel free to post a request at [meta] to have them changed. Until that change is made, please abide by the ones in effect now both in staying on-topic and being polite toward other users. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think I said something offensive. I am sorry Dude I don't have time for you, just leave me alone.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well, this is not exactly an article about it, but it covers most of what we use on auth and roles in  Sentry2. So, basically you have to

Install composer by executing

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```

Put it on a executable folder, renaming it

```
sudo mv composer.phar /bin/composer
```

Set the executable bit

```
sudo chmod +x /bin/composer
```

Install laravel by executing

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel
```

Install Sentry 2

```
composer require cartalyst/sentry:2.0.*
```

Then you just have to use Sentry:

Create your user groups and permissions for each group:

```
Sentry::getGroupProvider()->create(array(
    'name'        => 'Super Administrators',
    'permissions' => array(
            'system' => 1,
    ),
));

Sentry::getGroupProvider()->create(array(
    'name'        => 'Managers',
    'permissions' => array(
        'system.articles' => 1,
    ),
));

Sentry::getGroupProvider()->create(array(
    'name'        => 'Publishers',
    'permissions' => array(
        'system.articles.add' => 1,
        'system.articles.edit' => 1,
        'system.articles.delete' => 1,
        'system.articles.publish' => 1,
    ),
));

Sentry::getGroupProvider()->create(array(
    'name'        => 'Authors',
    'permissions' => array(
        'system.articles.add' => 1,
        'system.articles.edit' => 1,
        'system.articles.delete' => 1,
    ),
));
```

Set a group to a particular user, in this case it is setting Managers to the current logged user

```
Sentry::getUser()->addGroup( Sentry::getGroupProvider()->findByName('Author') );
```

Check if a user can publish and an added article

```
if ( Sentry::getUser()->hasAnyAccess(['system','system.articles','system.articles.publish']) )
{
    // will be able to publish something
}
```

Check if a user is Super Administrator (only this group has the 'system' access)

```
if ( Sentry::getUser()->hasAnyAccess(['system']) )
{
    // will be able to do a thing
}
```

Get all groups from a particular user

```
try
{
    // Find the user using the user id
    $user = Sentry::getUserProvider()->findById(1);

    // Get the user groups
    $groups = $user->getGroups();
}
catch (Cartalyst\Sentry\Users\UserNotFoundException $e)
{
    echo 'User was not found.';
}
```

Comment: This is pretty good. I just needed an example to get started. I will be able to figure it out from here. Thanks.

Comment: Added some steps to install Composer, Laravel and Sentry.

Comment: "Create your user groups and permissions for each group:" - where is the best place to put this?

Comment: Since you're going to do this everytime you need a new group. You can create a command. Or you can create a controller+views to create them via forms. I used to do it via Seeds, but now I think this is the wrong place to be in.

Comment: we can now use the [] array shortcut in PHP ....WHHHHAAAT! mind has been blown.......

Comment: In PHP 5.4+, yes we can!

Comment: Can we write it in autoload.php?

Comment: You better use `bootstrap/start.php`.

Comment: This sounds like a job for Artisan! - http://laravel.com/docs/commands#building-a-command